# Incompatible argument type error (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I am new in magento 2.

I am getting this error

```
    Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
    Neo\Pincode\Controller\Index\Index
        Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context. Actual type: array; File: 
/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Neo/Pincode/Controller/Index/Index.php
```

I want to try logs in magento 2 so in my contructor I have added DI for log like this,

the file causing error,

```
<?php

namespace Neo\Pincode\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, //log injection
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_logger->addDebug('some text or variable');
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Please help, to overcome this issue.

Comment: remove comma at end from \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, here and remove var folder

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
<?php

namespace Neo\Pincode\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger //log injection
    )
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_logger->addDebug('some text or variable');
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks frank, I found another solution also, but this one also worked